# Not expected behavior GitLab pipeline (needs/when)

Tags: gitlab, cicd

[image]

**cleanup** job are defined as:

```
cleanup:
  stage:e2e
  needs:
    - job: deploy
  stage: e2e
  script:
    - make clean
  resource_group: development
  when: always
```

Main goal is to run **cleanup** job when **deploy** job *successes* or *failed* (whatever) why i use `when:always` and added `needs:- job: deploy`.

But problem is if any previous job failed it also trigger to run **cleanup** job, even if **deploy** job does not run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `when: always` definition from you jobs config.
Instead you should adjust your `needs` to be optional like given below - that way pipeline will run

```yaml
cleanup:
  stage: e2e
  needs:
    - job: deploy
      optional: true
  script:
    - make clean
  resource_group: development
```

Another thing you could try would be to change your rules to say run this job `on_success` or `on_failure`

```yaml
cleanup:
  stage: e2e
  needs:
    - job: deploy
  script:
    - make clean
  resource_group: development
  rules:
    # Dummy if rule to showcase multiple rules
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: manual
    - when: on_success
    - when: on_failure
```

That second way the job would run if previous job succeeds and also if not, but would be limited to execution after deploy job is run.

Did not test this but I think this might work.

Comment: Actually cleanup job needs on 2 jobs, and 1 option not work because when one of them skip cleanup also skip.

Comment: But second looks like works, but i have another rule IF: ***. How it could be collaborate with two "when" ?

Comment: I edited my answer to showcase the use of a combination of if rule and when keyword within it. You can add a rule with `if` and `when` keyword. The important thing would be the order of the rules since the GitLab runner evaluates the rules in order until first matching rule